# Routing Data (Ethernet) + power on the same connector

Tags: power, connector, impedance, ethernet, emc

In order to ruggedize our connections and cables, I'm planning to route several data (CAN and Ethernet) signals and also some 230V AC power on the same connector.
The connector in question would be something similar to [this reference](https://www.amphenol-sine.com/AHDP02-24-35PR-SRA-35-positions-sealed-panel-mount-receptacle-pin-size-24-reduced-seal-smooth-ring-adapter_p_11059.html).

I know the impedance might not be respected for the ethernet and CAN busses but would that really be a significant problem on such small lengths (just to go through the connector basically) ?

What about the 230V/50Hz, should I expect some significant perturbations coming from it?

Thanks for the feedback,

Comment: it might be relevant; even a short unmatched connector has bad effects on signal integrity. At which speeds to you operate Ethernet (and CAN)?

Comment: (by the way, I *bet* amphenol has excellent technical sales. Chat with them/drop them an email describing what you need to transport. They might know the impedance properties of their connectors, and especially their applicability to common industrial communication buses)

Comment: sounds like bad juju - both from interference and safety. Just don't do it. Maybe wired mains and optic fiber.

Comment: [Harting](https://www.harting.com/DE/en-gb) makes several types of industrial connectors for such applications. Industrial prices to match.

Comment: Amphenol does make impedance-matched quadrax contacts for 10/100 and 10/1000 ethernet that are designed to go into their 38999 series connectors.  I'm not sure if they have ones for the DuraMate family, but that could be an option.  38999s might be worth looking into since their mil certification means that you will have multiple manufacturers.  That said, we routinely run 10/100 through standard (non-impedance matched) 38999 pins with no problem; just make sure they are adjacent to each other.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.
@MarcusMüller : It will not be anything super exotic, probably 100 or 1GBps max.
Amphenol and co. definitely have the exact connectors I'm looking for as rdtsc also mentioned and yes, they are out of our price range :-)

Comment: @vir : when you say, make sure they are not adjacent to each other, you're talking about ethernet and mains, right? I was actually planning to get the pairs as close to one another as possible... Am I in the wrong?

Comment: @VoltsAndNuts for 10 Mb/s I'd say, pff go with it. For 100 Mb/s, I'd say, OK, short cables on both ends, make sure the twisted pairs stay together and are separated by ground pins from other data and noisy power lines, but for 1 Gb/s ethernet? Wrong connector.

Comment: Just make sure the ethernet pair +/- pins are all adjacent to each other; the pairs themselves can probably be separated a bit.  I can't speak to how 50/60Hz might interact with them in adjacent cavities since we only run DC through our connectors.  You could also try the RJFTV series which is a second connector but might be easier to integrate with your existing equipment.

Answer (score 3):

> I know the impedance might not be respected for the ethernet and CAN busses but would that really be a significant problem on such small lengths (just to go through the connector basically) ?

For small lengths impedance mismatch shouldn't be a problem. The receiver should be able to recover data with ringing and reflections.

---

> What about the 230V/50Hz, should I expect some significant perturbations coming from it?

In this EMC/EMI scenario Ethernet and CAN are the victims.

I don't think you will have data integrity problems because the MAC layers of those 2 interfaces are robust and rely on retransmissions.

---

The problems I see here are **Electrical safety** and **Fire safety**.

1. **Electrical safety**

Running the mains close to data wires may be hazardous.

Take a look here:
https://www.truecable.com/blogs/cable-academy/running-ethernet-and-power-cable#

Google this: "mains and ethernet in the same cable"

2. **Fire safety**

Take a look here:

https://www.belden.com/blogs/600v-industrial-ethernet-cable-safety-and-nec-considerations

Comment: Hi Enrico,

Yes indeed, I might not have phrased it the right way but of course Data integrity of CAN & Ethernet will be the victims.
Regarding safety, I do not plan to route the wires in the same cable, it will be actually a 3G1,5 (or smaller) cable + several ethernet cables but all going to the same connector (which is 250V rated himself).